# Devices list aren't show on Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

After updating 12.04, my HDD partitions and USB storage devices was removed from the devices list on Nautilus Sidebar, only the "floppy0" is there.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

I can see all of them with Disk Utility. I can mount them and add them to computer list on Nautilus (not to device list).

I can't see any device in `/media`, only "floppy", "floppy0" and "cdrom" folders.

---

fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass> proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation UUID=ec9a8bbb-4cf0-4599-bf0e-85f7e3de6302 /               ext4   
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation UUID=88002a18-0f7f-4e7a-87b7-ef8e9f6388c8 none            swap    sw  
0       0 /dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto   
rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Comment: Can you try starting the "Disk Manager" program and post a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount your partitions automatically on startup.

A very good tutorial on Ubuntu wiki on how to achieve it is given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Per-User_Mounts).

You can also edit your `/etc/fstab` file, however it is more complex and generally not recommended if you've less experience.

> `/etc/fstab` contains information of where your partitions and storage
>   devices should be mounted and how.

The Ubuntu wiki also explains how you can edit the `fstab` file: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Editing_Ubuntu.27s_filesystem_table).

*Additional References: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html*

---

The program that causes the nautilus to show the devices is `gvfs-gdu-volume`.

Check if it's running:

```
sudo ps -e | grep gvfs-gdu-volume
```

I got the following output:

```
1983 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gdu-volume
```

If not, reinstall the package gvfs:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs
```

Comment: İt isn't my questions answer. I don't want to make an automount. I want to solve this problem http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/2739/ekrangrnts2012082516541.png where is my devices? Before uptade, there is.

Comment: check the update

Comment: I got "1503 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gdu-volume" and didn't solved any problem. Than I reinstalled gvfs and that didn't solve anything too. (I rebooted system after reinstall)

Comment: post the content of your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: What about nautilus permisions? I have got an error for "sudo nautilus" once, but now this error isn't seen. 

When I switched my system language and make logout, login; problem is solving but rebooting is making problem again..

Comment: though,this is not an answer to the question, if you want to run nautilus with sudo permission you have to use this command "gksudo nautilus" and if you want it with su permission you have to use it with this command "gksu nautilus"

Comment: Nautilus, when run using `gksu nautilus` or `sudo nautilus` won't show all the devices.

Comment: changing language>logout>login solves problem but after a reboot problem appear again (in changed language too). or logout>change desktop to unity2D> login solves problem too but rebooting is makes this problem again?

Answer (score 0):

remove:

> 0       0 /dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto

from fstab worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your device list in Nautilus is empty because your gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor is dead (or not started in time).

Just rerun it (as user) from Alt-F2 prompt

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 Alt-F2 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor]

or from your terminal:

```
$ /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor &
```

HTH.

Answer (score -2):

I am sure you are running nautilus in root or else you logged in as root.
open terminal and check whether root@"name" is written that means you are logged in as root

Comment: Logging in as root *on a graphical login screen* does not work. Theoretically this could be enabled but it's not as simple as setting a password for `root` and in any case someone who'd enable full graphical root sessions (a bad idea!) would almost certainly know they did so. On the other hand, it's much easier (and sometimes appropriate) to run Nautilus as root (with `gksudo nautilus` or `sudo -H nautilus` or the like). It's possible that devices mounted by one user wouldn't be shown by Nautilus running as another... but *the prompt in a new terminal won't show what user's running Nautilus!*